# Xcode not recognizing

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to format the number using following methods. which are available in "NsNumberFormatter" but Xcode not recognizing those methods. Its showing error as
"Receiver type 'NSNumberFormatter' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'setHasThousandSeparators'. Getting same error for second method also

```
setHasThousadSeparators: 
setThousandSeparator:

 currentVal = [currentVal stringByAppendingString:str];
        NSLog(@"Current Val is %@",currentVal);
        NSNumberFormatter * myNumFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

        [myNumFormatter setThousandseparator:@","];
        NSNumber *tempNum = [myNumFormatter numberFromString:currentVal];
        NSLog(@"My number is %@",tempNum);

        [display setText:[myNumFormatter stringFromNumber:tempNum]];
        currentVal=display.text;
```

Comment: Show the code where you are using it.

Comment: Where in you rcode is the error shown? As far as I can see there is no "setHasThousandSeparators" at all. However, i donnot undertand the first two lines of your code example. BTW: the Selector is "setHasThousandSeparators:" not "setHasThousandSeparators". Wherever the error is, you simply may have to add ":YES". "setHasThousandSeparators:YES";

Answer (score 0):

[myNumFormatter setThousandseparator:@","];

You have not capitalized properly. See the "s". Should be "S".

Comment: Even though xcode not recognizing those two methods.... Generally methods will be displayed when we write first letter of them but these two methods are not being displayed like so..

Comment: before giving negative votes plz check whether that method is working  or not... generally xcode will give us list of available methods just by clicking first letter. Guys once plz check whether this method is being displayed  or not.